# Orchard CMS Virto e-commerce module

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, e-commerce, orchardcms, virtocommerce

I developed previous web-applications with Orchard CMS and I enjoyed working with it. Now I started to create an E-commerce application and found out that Orchard has some modules for this so installed the Virto-commerce module but I'm starting to notice the lack of functionalities.

For example I can not figure out (lack of documentation) how to place attribute filters on de products page. Is it even possible?

Can the module be used to create a fully functional webshop like http://demo.virtocommerce.com/electronics/camcorders or is it very limited with just basic functionally?

Comment: Is there a reason to go with Orchard for an eCommerce project instead of using virto, or any other ecommerce platform directly?

Comment: I like the idea that I can use the same base (orchard) for every project and activate modules (like eCommerce) when they are needed in just one click. Everything is connected this way and easy to maintain.

Comment: Ok I understand that. We thought the same, but in the end used nopCommerce again. Developing an extensive ecommerce solution on orchard is absolutely possible, but requires quite some time.
Even if you would use a module like Virto, you would either have to manage two backends or build interfaces into orchard to communicate with the shop software.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The module for CMS Orchard is really simple and was developed only for demo-purposes - just to show that it is possible to use VirtoCommerce API with Orchard. So, for now this module has very limited functionality - only placing widgets on corresponding pages - and can not be used for creating a real-world e-commerce web site.

Actually we are open for your suggestions about integration VirtoCommerce and CMS Orchard.